# TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

```
# Import Packages
import random

# Global Variables
perf_num = 500
species = [20]
temp_num = 0
length = 0
s = 0

# Main Program
for num in range(100):
    r1 = int(random.random()*10)
    r2 = int(random.random()*10)
    species.append(r1)
    length = len(species)
    while s < length:
        print(s)
        if species[s-1] > species[s]:
            temp_num = species[s-1] - r1
            species[s-1] = temp_num
        else:
            temp_num = species[s] - r1
            species[s] = temp_num
        if s-1 < 5:
            species[s-1] = []
        s += 1

    print(species)
```

Please don't explain in very complicated coding language as I just started learning Python from youtube. I tried making my own program and continue to get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line:

```
species[s-1] = []
```

you're assigning an empty list to a list of numbers, which results in something like:

```
20 [20, 2] 2
```

Then when you try to compare a number and a list:

```
if species[s-1] > species[s]:
```

you'll get that error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()
```

Comment: Actually, the error happens on the line `if species[s-1] > species[s]:`. This is only in python 3, the error doesn't happen in python 2 (all types can be compared in python 2), so you get a different error at the subtraction operation.

Comment: The error in python2 is a _different_ one: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`

Comment: @Random832 hmmm... I'll check it out when I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: @Random832 Thx, I think your right but do you have any idea how could ffix this error or do what i want to do in a different way? Plz answer ASAP. rly need to get this done for a school project

Comment: @alfasin Any idea how I could still do what i want to do without getting this error?

Comment: @user3927678 if you would only describe what is it that you're trying to do there... Assuming we'll read the code and understand what you wanted to do is most of the times a real long shot ;)

Comment: @alfasin Ya sorry the program is supposed simulate evolution so every cycle of the while loop, the numbers duplicate into (hypothetically) more species. And bigger numbers (species) eat smaller numbers causing their number to become smaller. In that line, "species[s-1] = []" I am trying to remove a number which is too small to survive from the list. So if i don't use that How else do I remove something from the list?

Comment: @Vansh03 instead try: `del species[s-1]`

Comment: @alfasin NOw I'm getting the Error IndexError: "list index out of range"

Comment: @alfasin in the line "if species[s-1] > species[s]:"

Comment: Start with `s = length - 1` and go down `while s > -1:` decrement s: `s -= 1`